# php in a shortcode

Tags: shortcode

One of the major problems I have with a big site is the number of templates. So I figure I could call an optional footer within the page using a shortcode.

```
function trainer_footer( ){
 get_footer('rctrainer');
}
add_shortcode( 'trainer', 'trainer_footer' );
```

This works.

But there are two questions;

1. the content of sidebar-trainer appears at the top of the content rather than in the place of the shortcode. Why?
2. I've read it's not a good idea to write PHP into a shortcode like this. Why?

Answer (score 0):

1. First, `get_footer()` is meant to load page level template files,
   not post-level ones. You should be using `get_template_part()`
   instead.
2. Shortcodes execute as a filter on `the_content`. Per the norms of
   all filters, they should `return` content, not `echo` it. `echo`ing
   content will cause effects like you are seeing. Apparently, the
   template file you are loading with the shortcode is printing
   charaters to the screen instead of `return`ing a string as it should
   be.
3. I don't know where you've read that about shortcodes and PHP but it
   is is sort of nonsense, at least as you've presented the case.
   Shortcodes virtually all do more, much more, than `echo` static
   strings-- take a look at the Core gallery shortcode, for example. To do that, you need PHP.

Answer (score 0):

1. Probably because of not closed DIVs or CSS. You have to check on the source code of the page.
2. There is a good practice (and also to avoid issues) to return shortcode content, instead of outputting it directly (which is what the get_footer() does).

Besides that, I really don't think you should use a shortcode to call a footer. I can see so many best ways better than that: using meta fields, page templates, even using basic ID comparison.